# Tool to validate JPA queries

Tags: sql, jpa

All,
is there a tool like an SQL client where I can validate a JPA query I get from my system logs/consoles?

Meaning, as I can validate a SQL query using a SQL client like Oracle SQL+ or SQL server client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vestigo](http://vestigo.nightlabs.com) is an Eclipse plug-in (or a stand-alone program, if you prefer that) having code-assist and -highlighting. You can execute your query on any JPA (or JDO) datastore.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it with Hibernate Tools Eclipse plugin (it's about HQL, but it can manage JPQL).